# Is there a single word for “one who explains his point of view very clearly”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word for a person who is able to explain himself very clearly and using the best possible words, etc.
I am not looking for "perspicuous", etc. The focus is more on the language part: someone who uses the right language and words to describe himself.
I know the word exists but its just skipping my head at the moment!!!
Please help.

Comment: try *succinct*, or *clear-headed*, or *rational*, or *eloquent*, or *loquacious* or... The question is too broad!

Comment: "I am not looking for *perspicious*, etc." Why is "etc:" wrong? How am I supposed to know if any of my suggestions above fit into the "etc." category?

Comment: [**Laconic**](http://findwords.info/term/laconic), concise, orator, silver-tongued ...

Comment: Boring, tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mean **eloquent** in this sense:

> 1. a. Of persons: Possessing or exercising the power of fluent, forcible, and appropriate expression.

["eloquent, adj.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/60591?redirectedFrom=eloquent (accessed November 17, 2015).]

Or maybe **lucid** in this sense:

> 4. Marked by clearness of reasoning, expression, or arrangement; easily intelligible.

["lucid, adj.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/110839?redirectedFrom=lucid (accessed November 17, 2015).]

Comment: "Eloquent", as well as "articulate" (as suggested by @Elian) are the words I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 2):

Consider,

***articulate***.

> expressing oneself easily in clear and effective language: an articulate speaker [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/articulate)

***facund***

> *adj.* eloquent, articulate
>   (from the GNU version of the Collaborative International Dictionary of English)
>
> *adj.* eloquent (from The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia)
>
> ready of speech; eloquent; fluent.
>   Also, *facundious*. [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/facund)

Answer (score 0):

***[Explicit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/explicit)*** may suggest the idea:

> - unreserved in expression; outspoken: *explicit language.*
> - fully and clearly expressed; leaving nothing implied: *explicit approval.*

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Describing the person as a **pithy speaker** could work:

> pithy: if something that is said or written is pithy, it is intelligent and strongly stated, **without wasting any words**

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pithy))

> 1. pithy: containing much meaning and substance in a terse concentrated form : **brief and to the point** : full of significance
> 2. pithy: marked by the use of pithy speech or writing
>      *a pithy speaker*
>      *a pithy style*

(Webster's Unabridged)

Depending on the context, other suitable words might be ***[succinct](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succinct)*** and ***[concise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concise)*** (mentioned in comments already.)